# can we load excel 2010 using SSIS 2008?

Tags: ssis

can we load Excel 2010 using SSIS 2008? since in Excel connection manager we have excel version option there we have microsoft excel 2007 as last option,if we want to load  excel 2010, how do we do it using ssis 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 2007 is valid for 2007 format going forward

[Excel Connection Manager Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186848.aspx)

```
Option          Description
Excel 97-2003   File was created using Excel 97 or later.
Excel 3.0       File was created using Excel 3.0.
Excel 4.0       File was created using Excel 4.0.
Excel 5.0       File was created using Excel 95 (7.0).
```